# Skipping till -(hyphen), and storing the name

Tags: c++, regex

I want to use regular expressions to skip until i find a (-)Hyphen and store whatever comes after. I tried a few things but it didn't work out.
This is an example string:

> Fall Down Seven Times; Stand Up Eight." -Naoki Higashida

I am just learning regular expressions and want to use them in my project to skip until I encounter different symbols.

*edit 1: this is what I have used so far, with some other stuff I found online.

```cpp
"(?:[a-zA-Z;.;""]*)[^-][a-zA-Z]*"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please show what you tried, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Can your quotes contain hyphens as well?

Comment: No, It cannot contain hyphen

Comment: "(?:[a-zA-Z;.;""]*)[^-][a-zA-Z]*" //this is what I have tried so far along with few other stuff I saw online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.*-(.*)`. The capture group will contain everything after the hyphen.

`.*` matches anything

`-` matches literal hyphen

`(.*)` matches anything and captures it

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ewcneg/1).